# How to implement robotium test case to capture pic from the application

Tags: android, junit, android-camera, automated-tests, robotium

I have succesfully implemented robotium test cases for my application except the capture pic from the application. I have tried below code to implement capture pic robotium test cases but It won't work for me.

```
//With Instrumentation
Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA);

//With Keycodes
solo.sendKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA);
TestUtils.setSleepTime();

//Layout level - getting the view references
Activity activity = solo.getCurrentActivity();
View groupView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) groupView;
final View childCount = group.getChildAt(0);
View childCount1 = null;

if(childCount instanceof ViewGroup){
    ViewGroup group1 = (ViewGroup) childCount;
    childCount1 = group1.getChildAt(0);
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to perform capture event with roboitum test case.

Comment: What do you mean by "capture pic from the application"?

Comment: There are some limitations refer: http://blog.mobinius.com/robotium-best-testing-framework-for-android/

Answer (score 2):

```
        solo.takeScreenshot("YourScreenshotFileName");
```

A screenshot will be saved to /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/. Requires permission to write to external storage. See http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/index.html

Comment: The case which i have mentioned in different scenario. I have a option like capture image button, when i click on this popup being displayed with options of "Choose from Gallery" and "Select Camera" when i select a camera option then application navigates to camera screen there i unable to perform any action. So what i'm expecting is the app should capture the pic and give back to the image and will be set to the imageview in the application.

Comment: You can't use robotium to do that because robotium can only run inside of your own app. It can't perform any actions inside the camera app.

Comment: Yes. For more details refer : http://blog.mobinius.com/robotium-best-testing-framework-for-android/